# How can I change the place of the js and css files generated by advagg to another place

Tags: css-js-aggregation

How can I change the place of the js and css files generated by advagg to another place, for example in a folder at the root of the site.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The assets output location [is configurable as of Drupal 10.1.0](https://www.drupal.org/node/3328126).